# My Mysql version is 8.0.18,But I can't use function JSON_VALUE

Tags: mysql

when I execute code :

```
 SELECT `name` FROM `list_search_test` WHERE JSON_VALUE(`info`, '$.sex') = 'male' AND JSON_OVERLAPS(JSON_VALUE(`info`, '$.hobby'), JSON_QUOTE('basketball'));
```

I get message is :

FUNCTION xxxx.JSON_VALUE does not exist

Who can tell me why?Thank you very much.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=68ebeef56ccd4286a7659477117bf41f) . What is `xxxx.` before `JSON_VALUE`?

Comment: xxxx is my db name.....

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 2):

I figure out,hh……

JSON_VALUE() was introduced in MySQL 8.0.21.

see: [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

so,I can't use it……

Too bad……